# Flask: getting an error after moving files to a different directory

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask project that I've been working on with two databases, offers.sqlite3, students.sqlite3.

I recently moved my files to a different directory and when I run my files, it gives an error. Why is this?

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danish/Documents/GitHub/ro-data-dashboard/app/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    db.init_app(app)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 310, in init_app
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.
```